# jQuery Animate SlideDown and then FIXED

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

The following code causes the top left menu block to scroll into view when the user scrolls past the bottom of its child menu.

The problem I am having is changing the menu to FIXED once it scrolls into view.  Currently, it continues to animate into view with each scroll.

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/GregsFiddle/rUsRz/

JS Below:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( jQuery ) { 

if ($("#autofixmenu")[0]){

var $autofixmenu   = $("#autofixmenu"),
        $bottom    = $('#categories'),
        $window    = $(document),
        offsetbtm  = $bottom.offset(),
        offset     = $autofixmenu.offset(),
        topPadding = 70;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > $autofixmenu.height() ) {
            $autofixmenu.stop().addClass('autofixed').animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $autofixmenu.stop().removeClass('autofixed').animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }

    });
}
});
```

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xATBt/ Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Almost, I dont see the first menu being animated into view there.  If I scroll down quickly, Id like for the menu to be delayed scrolling into view- and then become fixed.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. Can you check again?

Comment: I will test it on my live site, but it appears the blue box scrolls down along with the red box.  I only want the red to scroll down.

Comment: I posted an answer myself as well.  Take a look and tell me what you think.  The code you shared drops the wrong box down for some reason.  But I fully appreciate your assistance

Comment: My Bad, I forgot to save the changes. Here is the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/fHzx8/

Comment: yep that did it. thanks a million.  if you reply with that as the answer ill select it as the best.  thank you for your help!

Comment: Done. Please find the answer posted. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified Javascript.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) { 
    if ($("#autofixmenu")[0]){
        var $autofixmenu   = $("#autofixmenu"),
                $bottom    = $('#categories'),
                $window    = $(document),
                offsetbtm  = $bottom.offset(),
                offset     = $autofixmenu.offset(),
                topPadding = 70;

        $window.scroll(function() {
            if ($window.scrollTop() > $autofixmenu.height() ) {
                if($autofixmenu.hasClass('autofixed') === false) {
                    $autofixmenu.addClass('absolute');
                    $autofixmenu.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    }, function() {
                        $autofixmenu.removeClass('absolute').addClass('autofixed').css('margin-top', '');
                    });
                }
            } else {
                $autofixmenu.stop().removeClass('autofixed').animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You also need the following css changes

```
.autofixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: auto;
    top: 70px;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am understading your problem...you want to fix the div once it get on fixed prosition.

if is it than you have to change the .animate to .css

See below code.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( jQuery ) { 

if ($("#autofixmenu")[0]){

var $autofixmenu   = $("#autofixmenu"),
        $bottom    = $('#categories'),
        $window    = $(document),
        offsetbtm  = $bottom.offset(),
        offset     = $autofixmenu.offset(),
        topPadding = 70;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > $autofixmenu.height() ) {
            $autofixmenu.stop().addClass('autofixed').css({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $autofixmenu.stop().removeClass('autofixed').css({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }

    });
}
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want HOWEVER I still want to retain the first instance of animate.  Id like it to .animate when it scrolls into view- and then once its done become fixed position.

Comment: can you pls up the answer if it helps you.